# Is the hdSeedid in Bitcoin Core 0.17 RPC the actual seed itself?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, seed

I'm trying to find out the seed for the HD wallet in the 0.17 release of Bitcoin Core. I used the `getwalletinfo` command in the RPC console which produced information which includes a string that it calls `hdseedid`, which curiously is the same as the string it calls `hdmasterkeyid`.

My question is - is that string the actual HD seed itself, and if not, how would I find/display it?

Any clarifications appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hdseedid` is the same as the `hdmasterkeyid` (the latter is retained for legacy reasons, it was renamed to `hdseedid` for better clarity). It is the HASH160 of the HD seed.

If you wish the retrieve the seed, unlock your wallet and run:

```
dumpwallet /some/filepath/wallet.txt
```

In the dumped wallet, you should find an `xprv` key, which is your master extended key. Note that Bitcoin Core does not support BIP39, and the xprv cannot be converted to seed words.